# determine the average time to look up a key in a randomly generated balanced binary search tree in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to determine the average amount of time it takes to loop up a key in a randomly generated balanced binary search tree, as a function of the size of the tree.. I'm unable to write the code to calculate the time.. so if i can get help or at least best way to write the code i would appreciate it... its been a while since i coded

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried?  Did anything in particular trip you up?  The more specific you are, the better we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Must be homework, and stop skipping class. The answer is `O(log n)`. Now go read the book and figure out why.

Comment: i know its O(log n) we learned that in class but my question about the coding part of it... Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> I'm unable to write the code to calculate the time

Use the "StopWatch" class to calculate *elapsed time*. It's documentation is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

You'll want to take measurements of *several* runs of the algorithm and possibly discard the first one. Remember, the first time that a method runs in a process, the JIT compiler has to jit compile all the code, which takes extra time. That could be throwing off your measurements.

Answer (score -1):

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now;
fncYourFonction();
var stopTime = DateTime.Now;

var elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;

 string time = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            elapsedTime .Hours, elapsedTime .Minutes, elapsedTime .Seconds,
            elapsedTime .Milliseconds / 10);
Console.WriteLine(time , "Elapsed Time");
```

Just replace fncYourFonction and you're done. Almost the same thing as @Eric's tutorial.